# Printing match groups with grep

Tags: sed, grep

I have the following grep:

```
grep -Po 'href="(http://.*)">Transcript.* - ([0-9]*)\. (.*)</a>'
```

I would like to print out the match groups. Is there a way to do this without Perl/Python? I tried using `sed`, but I couldn't manage to make it work -- probably due to syntax issues, I'm not really sure what needs to be escaped and what not.

Comment: Can you show an example URL that you're trying to parse with `grep`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -n 's|.*href="\(http://[^"]*\)">Transcript.* - \([0-9]*\)\. \(.*\)</a>|\1:\2:\3|p'
```

That only works if there's only one link per line.

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print for m|href="(http://.*?)">Transcript.*? - (\d*)\. (.*?)</a>|g'
```

Answer (score 1):

A native bash solution might work for you. This matches the entire line to the regular expression so will only work with one link per line scenarios

```
pat='href="(http://.*)">Transcript.* - ([0-9]*)\. (.*)</a>'
while IFS= read -r line; do 
   [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && 
   echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

grep can only print either the whole line or the part which matched the single pattern (or the filename, I guess).  However, since you're using a perl regex, you may want to try pcregrep, which has an additional optional parameter to the -o flag specifying the parenthetical group to show.  As in

```
sauer@humpy:~$ echo ab12cd34ef | pcregrep -o1 '.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
12
sauer@humpy:~$ echo ab12cd34ef | pcregrep -o2 '.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
34
```

Unfortunately, you can not specify multiple -o options (probably because you'd then need a separator and things would get ugly).  But if you're doing something simple, I suppose you could just repeat the pcregrep multiple times.

Also note that there can be no space between the "o" and match number in the command, since `-o` with no argument behaves the same as regular grep.

Personally, I'd just use perl.

```
sauer@humpy:~$ echo ab12cd34ef | perl -plne 's/^.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*$/$1:$2/'
12:34
```